# how to set visible true/false based on value in c# code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, code-behind

I have a list of input controls like `Date selector, Select box, textbox, checkbox`. I want to set visible true and false based on the type user selects.

I have tried the below is working but just wonder if I can make this Dry and make efficient calling from a single function or something. Any advice would be much appreciated.

Please ignore the naming of the text boxes or anything as this is just for an example.

```
if (attribute_type == "T") { 
  Value1_tbx.Visible = true; // this is true
  Value1_tbx.Text = some_text_value;  // and set some value
  Value_ddl.Visible = false; 
  Value_Date_tbx.Visible = false;
  Value_Date_calendar_img.Visible = false;
  Value_rbl.Visible = false;
} else if (attribute_type == "S") {
  Value1_tbx.Visible = false;
  Value_ddl.Visible = true; // this is true
  Value_ddl.Text = some_select_box_value; // and set some value
  Value_Date_tbx.Visible = false;
  Value_Date_calendar_img.Visible = false;
  Value_rbl.Visible = false;
} else if (attribute_type == 'D') {
  Value1_tbx.Visible = false;
  Value_ddl.Visible = false;
  Value_Date_tbx.Visible = true; // this is true
  Value_Date_calendar_img.Visible = true; // calendar icon should be visible
  Value_Date_tbx.Text = some_date_value; // and set some value
  Value_rbl.Visible = false;
} else if (attribute_type == 'R') {
  Value1_tbx.Visible = false;
  Value_ddl.Visible = false;
  Value_Date_tbx.Visible = false;
  Value_Date_calendar_img.Visible = false;
  Value_rbl.Visible = true; // this is true
  Value.rbl.Text = some_value; // and set some value
};
```

Comment: Is `attribute_type` a `string` or a `char`? You say *"the below is working"*, but the code shouldn't compile since you're comparing it to both types

Comment: As a side note, it would be easier to read if you set the values in the same order each time - it makes visual comparison easier.

Comment: @Rufusl It's a char. Thanks

Comment: I have edited and put it in the same order

Comment: You could set them all to false or true outside the first `if`. And then only hide the ones you don't need. It saves some duplicates.

Comment: An example would be much appreciated

Comment: I have updated my question and hope that's now easy to understand.

Answer (score 1):

In the comments of my other answer, I said if you were to write a single function you'd need to perform the checks still. However, you could write multiple individual functions that set the values of your controls. Doing this would alleviate having to perform the checks, but it *would* require more code.

Create your functions:

```
public void SetTControls()
{
     Value1_tbx.Visible = true;
     Value1_tbx.Text = some_text_value;
     Value_ddl.Visible = false; 
     Value_Date_tbx.Visible = false;
     Value_Date_calendar_img.Visible = false;
     Value_rbl.Visible = false;
}

public void SetSControls()
{
    Value1_tbx.Visible = false;
    Value_ddl.Visible = true;
    Value_ddl.Text = some_select_box_value;
    Value_Date_tbx.Visible = false;
    Value_Date_calendar_img.Visible = false;
    Value_rbl.Visible = false;
}

public void SetDControls()
{
    Value1_tbx.Visible = false;
    Value_ddl.Visible = false;
    Value_Date_tbx.Visible = true;
    Value_Date_calendar_img.Visible = true;
    Value_Date_tbx.Text = some_date_value;
    Value_rbl.Visible = false;
}

public void SetRControls()
{
    Value1_tbx.Visible = false;
    Value_ddl.Visible = false;
    Value_Date_tbx.Visible = false;
    Value_Date_calendar_img.Visible = false;
    Value_rbl.Visible = true;
    Value.rbl.Text = some_value;
}
```

Then you could clean up your if/else statement like this:

```
if (attribute_type == 'T')
    SetTControls(); 
else if (attribute_type == 'S')
    SetSControls();
else if (attribute_type == 'D')
    SetDControls();
else if (attribute_type == 'R')
    SetRControls();
```

As I said, it requires more code, but definitely cleans up your if/else statement. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If some of the values of your controls you're setting are the same based on the value of `attribute_type`, you could use a switch statement.

So for example if `Value_ddl.Visible = false` when `attribute_type == 'S'` or `attribute_type == 'D'`, you could do something like this:

```
switch(attribute_type)
{
     case 'S':
     case 'D':
          Value_ddl.Visible = false;
          break;
     default:
          //default stuff
          break;
}
```

It might save some space in your code and make it more readable.

Comment: I have updated my question and hope that's now easy to understand.

Comment: @Sri - I understand your question just fine. I was just giving you another option other than a convoluted if/else statement. Unfortunately, if you were to write a function that would do your setting of visibility for your controls, you'd still have to perform the check one way or another.

Comment: Thanks and I am not very keen on writing a function. Just wonder is there any way to organise this in a clear way of sorting out.

Comment: @Sri - Honestly though, there's nothing wrong with the way you're doing it. It's just a little hard to follow is all. Good luck!

Comment: @Sri - If either of these answers helped you, would you mind accepting one of them please?